# Netty 4 ReadTimeoutHandler not throwing in OioEventLoopGroup

Tags: java, netty, socketchannel

I'm new to netty. Is this an expected behaviour?

A bit more detailed:

```
public class Test {
  public static void connect(){
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    Bootstrap bs = new Bootstrap();
    bs.group(workerGroup);
    bs.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    bs.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);
    bs.handler( new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>(){
      @Override
      protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pl = ch.pipeline();
        pl.addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(1000,
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
          pl.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
            16384, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
          pl.addLast("string-decoder", new StringDecoder());
          pl.addLast("handler", 
            new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> (String.class){
              @Override
              protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                String msg) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(msg);
              }
              @Override
              protected void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                Throwable cause) throws Exception {
                if(cause instanceof ReadTimeoutException){
                  System.out.println("Timed out.");
                }
                ctx.close();
              }
          });
      }
    });
    bs.connect("127.0.0.1", 45001);
  }
}
```

This is just test case, so it might be a bit incorrect, pipeline ressembles my actual pipeline close enough though.

Basicly if I change `EventLoopGroup` initialization from `NioEventLoopGroup` to `OioEventLoopGroup` and bootstrap channel setup from `bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class)` to `bootstrap.channel(OioSocketChannel.class)` without touching anything else, `ReadTimeoutHandler` stops throwing `ReadTimeoutExceptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Netty 4.0.4.Final . Please upgrade, see [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1614

Comment: Oops didnt notice that one. Thank you.